# Error: checking AWS STS access – cannot get role ARN for current session: MissingEndpoint: 'Endpoint' configuration is required for this service

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, cluster-computing, amazon-eks, eksctl

I created a `cluster.yaml` file which contains the below information:

```
---
apiVersion: eksctl.io/v1alpha5
kind: ClusterConfig
metadata:
  name: eks-litmus-demo
  region: ${AWS_REGION}
  version: "1.21"
managedNodeGroups:
  - instanceType: m5.large
    amiFamily: AmazonLinux2
    name: eks-litmus-demo-ng
    desiredCapacity: 2
    minSize: 2
    maxSize: 4
EOF
```

When i run `$ eksctl create cluster -f cluster.yaml` to create the cluster through my terminal, I get the below error:

**Error: checking AWS STS access – cannot get role ARN for current session: MissingEndpoint: 'Endpoint' configuration is required for this service**

How can I resolve this? Please help!!!

Note: I have the global and regional endpoints under STS set to "valid in all AWS regions".

Comment: Can you post "cluster.yaml" to your quesiton.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 4):

In my case, it was a typo in the region. I had `us-east1` as the value. When it is corrected to `us-east-1`, the error disappeared. So it is worth checking if there are typos in any of the fields.

Answer (score 4):

mention `--profile` if you use any aws profile other than `default`

```bash
eksctl create cluster -f cluster.yaml --profile <profile-name>
```

Answer (score 2):

My SSO session token had expired:

`aws sts get-caller-identity --profile default`

> The SSO session associated with this profile has expired or is otherwise invalid. To refresh this SSO session run `aws sso login` with the corresponding profile.

Then I needed to refresh my SSO session token:

`aws sso login`

```
Attempting to automatically open the SSO authorization page in your default browser.
If the browser does not open or you wish to use a different device to authorize this request, open the following URL:

https://device.sso.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/

Then enter the code:

XXXX-XXXX
Successfully logged into Start URL: https://XXXX.awsapps.com/start
```

Comment: I've forgoten to add the --profile {my-profile}

Answer (score 0):

**Error: checking AWS STS access – cannot get role ARN for current session:**

According to this, I think its not able to get the role (in your case, cluster creator's role) which is responsible to create the cluster.
Create an IAM user with appropriate role. Attach necessary policies to that role to create the EKS cluster.
Then you can use **aws configure** command to add the *AWS Access Key ID*, *AWS Secret Access Key*, and *Default region name*.

[Make sure that the user has the appropriate access to create and access the eks cluster in your aws account. You can use aws cli to verify if you have the appropriate access]

Answer (score 0):

It is important to configure the default profile for AWS CLI correctly on the command line using

```
set AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID <your_access_key>

set AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY <your_secret_key>
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolved in my case it show me this error [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/inXuk.png)
Solution  - go to home directory open .aws folder check region i have update it as default and  its resolved

Answer (score 0):

In my case i just have to add `--region eu-west-1` and it works. Just make sure you pass in the region flag

Answer (score 0):

I was getting same error when trying to create cluster for the demo:

```
eksctl create cluster --name EKS-Cluster  --region eu-west-2a --node-type t2.small
```

The AZ was eu-west-2a' but needed to remove 'a' at the end of the AZ name. That resolved for me.